# Auto generate business objects from entity framework plus auto mapping

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For a large project with hundreds of tables, is there a way to automatically generate the business objects based on the .edmx file rather than to create them manually one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use custom t4 templates to generate them.  If you then need to edit them manually, i guess you could make them partial but then you'd need to make the other half of the partial class manually.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx